# Problem in PS2PDF file size

Tags: pdf, ubuntu, ps, bash

I am using `gnuplot` to plot an input file. I pass this file to `gnuplot` from a bash script and the output is `.ps`. Then I convert it to pdf in my bash script, but the pdf cuts the rest of the plot off. I have *tons* of data in the input file and the plot is very big, the pdf file only shows the first hundred values and the rest is not there and I cannot even scroll left or right. Any help?

Here is the script I used:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sed -i 's/ns/;/g' /dev/shm/waitingTime$1.txt
sed -i 's/ns/;/g' /dev/shm/thinkingTime$1.txt
gnuplot -e "fileW='/dev/shm/waitingTime$1.txt'; fileT='/dev/shm/thinkingTime$1.txt'; wtout='/dev/shm/wt$1.ps'; ttout='/dev/shm/tt$1.ps'" file.gnuplot
cat /dev/shm/wt$1.ps | ps2pdf - /dev/shm/wt$1.pdf
cat /dev/shm/tt$1.ps | ps2pdf - /dev/shm/tt$1.pdf
```

Comment: You are aware that `gnuplot` can produce `.pdf` already -- there's no need to convert from `.ps` to `.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this may sound stupid, but maybe there is a character or something in the `ps` files which gets lost during `cat`? Maybe something nonprintable or something? Instead of piping the files to `stdin` of `ps2pdf`, maybe you can use GhostScript directly? Below I add two commands doing this (invoking GhostScript via `gs`). Just for good measures (but likely unnecessary), I included some switches which make sure that everything is included (fonts, raster images are not modified), etc.

```
gs -q -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dCompressFonts=true -dOptimize=true -dPreserveCopyPage=false -dPreserveEPSInfo=false -dPreserveHalftoneInfo=false -dPreserveOPIComments=false -dPreserveOverprintSettings=false -dPreserveSeparation=false -dPreserveDeviceN=false -dMaxBitmap=2147483647 -dDownsampleMonoImages=false -dDownsampleGrayImages=false -dDownsampleColorImages=false -dDetectDuplicateImages=true -dHaveTransparency=true -dFastWebView=false -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage -sOutputFile=/dev/shm/wt$1.pdf /dev/shm/wt$1.ps -c ".setpdfwrite <</NeverEmbed [ ]>> setdistillerparams"

gs -q -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dCompressFonts=true -dOptimize=true -dPreserveCopyPage=false -dPreserveEPSInfo=false -dPreserveHalftoneInfo=false -dPreserveOPIComments=false -dPreserveOverprintSettings=false -dPreserveSeparation=false -dPreserveDeviceN=false -dMaxBitmap=2147483647 -dDownsampleMonoImages=false -dDownsampleGrayImages=false -dDownsampleColorImages=false -dDetectDuplicateImages=true -dHaveTransparency=true -dFastWebView=false -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage -sOutputFile=/dev/shm/tt$1.pdf /dev/shm/tt$1.ps -c ".setpdfwrite <</NeverEmbed [ ]>> setdistillerparams"
```

or you could use `ps2pdf` directly (meaning something like `ps2pdf tt$1.ps`) ... ...anyway, I am not sure about the advantage of `cat`, except that it adds something additional that could fail (then again, I also copy-pasted all my favourite switches...)